# dynamically specify data type for a column in mysql?

Tags: mysql

i have one problem that, i have to change type of data in column based on foreign key stored in that row.

```
unit_id   unit_name
1          String
2          Float
3          Date
4          Int


Id      spec value   unit id
1         "A"         1
2         30.90       2
3         null        3
4         100         4
```

now i should achieve the above condition. how do i achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. What you can do:

- Use VARCHAR (or something similar) for `spec value`, and parse the content yourself.
- Have several columns (`spec value_string`, `spec value_float`, ...) Problem: The table will contain lots of null values. But this approach can often be seen for reporting tables.
- Have several tables, one for strings, one for floats, and join them with the datatype table depending on `unit_name`.

Comment: which one you would choose for a specs comparison app of mobile phones I will have a table with the specs that have a spec_id and spec_value, but than I need to make casting in the query or on server for sorting and ordering the data?